# Check points is inside a polygon - doesn't work correct

Tags: three.js, collision-detection, raycasting

I create a room based on any Array with points. Objects that can be moved are added to the room.
The goal is to block the possibility of moving the object out of the room.

When the object is moved, I check if all 4 bottom points belong to the floor - if so, you can move the object further - if not, it means that the object would go behind the wall, so you have to restore it to the previous position.

The function responsible for creating room (wallsPoint is a Array with points)

```
var wallPoint = [
 {
   "X": 0,
   "Y": 0
 },
 {
   "X": 5,
   "Y": 0
},
 {
  "X": 5,
  "Y": 3
},
{
  "X": 7,
  "Y": 3
},
{
  "X": 7,
  "Y": 5
},
{
  "X": 5,
  "Y": 5
},
{
  "X": 5,
  "Y": 7
},
{
  "X": 0,
  "Y": 7
}
 ];

function createRoom() {

// create a walls
var walls = new THREE.Geometry();
var floorPoints = [];


wallsPoint.forEach(r => {
    walls.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(r.X, r.Y, 0));
walls.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(r.X, r.Y, 3));
floorPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(r.X, r.Y, 0));

walls.name = "wall";
});
    var previousVertexIndex = walls.vertices.length - 2;
    for (i = 0; i < walls.vertices.length; i += 2) {
        walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i + 1, i, 
previousVertexIndex));
       walls.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(previousVertexIndex + 1, i + 
1, previousVertexIndex));
       previousVertexIndex = i;

    }
    walls.computeFaceNormals();

var wallsTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'walls.jpg' );//  
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(walls, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: wallsTexture
}));
mesh.rotation.x= -Math.PI /2;

//create a floor
var floorShape = new THREE.Shape(floorPoints);
var floorGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(floorShape);
var floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'wood.jpg' ); 
floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: floorTexture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
}));


floor.geometry.vertices = floorPoints;
floor.geometry.name = "floor";
floor.rotation.x =-Math.PI/2;

group = new THREE.Object3D();
group.add(mesh);
group.add( floor );
group.add(ceiling) ;
scene.add( group );
  }
```

The function responsible to check if the points are on the floor. 
Points are a helperBox.geometry.attributes.position.array (helper box for an object that we move with the mouse)

```
function checkPoints(points){

var arrayToCheck = [new THREE.Vector3(points[6],points[7],points[8]),new THREE.Vector3(points[9],points[10],points[11]),new THREE.Vector3(points[18],points[19], points[20]),new THREE.Vector3(points[21],points[22],points[23])];


var inside = [];
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

for(var i = 0; i<arrayToCheck.length; i++){
    var pointToCheck = arrayToCheck[i];
    raycaster.set(pointToCheck, new THREE.Vector3(1,1,1));
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(floor);

    if( intersects.length %2 === 1) {
        inside.push(true);
        console.log(true);
    }
    else{
        inside.push(false);
        console.log(false);
    }
}
if(!inside.includes(false)){
    return true
}
else{
    return false
}
 }
```

I want the checkPoints function to show true or false depending on whether all 4 points are on the floor or not.
Currently, in most cases, the function works well. Unfortunately, not all of them. Every time it works bad - it's about point 3 and / or 4.

How to fix it?
Alternatively, how else should not let the object (model is format obj - so irregular shape) go beyond the floor?

Comment: Have a look at [this algorithm](https://www.ignatiuz.com/blog/gis/how-to-check-whether-point-lies-inside-outside-the-polygon/)

Comment: What is the purpose of `if( intersects.length %2 === 1) {`?

Comment: @Mugen87  If the number of edges it passed through is odd, then it’s in the polygon.

Comment: @prisoner849 I have read the algorithm but I can not convert it into my code; but thank you - maybe it still lights me up :)

Answer (score 2):

A very rough concept with implementation of the algorithm, taken from https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(3.5, 10, 3.5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.target.set(3.5, 0, -3.5);
controls.update();

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(20, 20, 0x44ff44);
grid.position.set(0, -0.01, 0);
scene.add(grid);

var wallPoints = wallsPoint.map(w => {
  return new THREE.Vector3(w.X, 0, -w.Y)
});
var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(wallPoints);
var points = new THREE.Points(geom, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  size: 1,
  color: "red"
}));
var lines = new THREE.LineLoop(geom, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: "yellow"
}));

scene.add(points, lines);

var marker = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.25, 8, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "aqua"
}));
marker.position.set(3.5, 3.5, 0);
scene.add(marker);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0);
var iPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, marker.position);
  marker.material.color.set(isInside(marker.position, wallPoints) ? "aqua" : "magenta");
}

function isInside(point, vs) {

  var x = point.x,
    y = point.z;

  var inside = false;
  for (var i = 0, j = vs.length - 1; i < vs.length; j = i++) {
    var xi = vs[i].x,
      yi = vs[i].z;
    var xj = vs[j].x,
      yj = vs[j].z;

    var intersect = ((yi > y) != (yj > y)) &&
      (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi);
    if (intersect) inside = !inside;
  }

  return inside;
}

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
  var wallsPoint = [{
      "X": 0,
      "Y": 0
    },
    {
      "X": 5,
      "Y": 0
    },
    {
      "X": 5,
      "Y": 3
    },
    {
      "X": 7,
      "Y": 3
    },
    {
      "X": 7,
      "Y": 5
    },
    {
      "X": 5,
      "Y": 5
    },
    {
      "X": 5,
      "Y": 7
    },
    {
      "X": 0,
      "Y": 7
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: In my case is a rotation and orbitControls (i don't know why orbitControls doesn't work in codepen,so in this code missing orbitControls)  - and your solution doesn't work correctly. 
Look at:  https://codepen.io/jagodanat/pen/WWmqZm;

Comment: Can you come to the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/) with this question? Your codepen involves more questions :)

Comment: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/check-points-is-inside-a-polygon-doesnt-work-correct/7291  :)